# pandas update only true values with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, updates

I have the following two tables:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'val1': [True, False, False, True], 
                         'val2': [False, True, False, True], 
                         'val3': [True, True, False, True]},
                   index=pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], name='index'))
```

| index | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | False | True |
| 2 | False | True | True |
| 3 | False | False | False |
| 4 | True | True | True |

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'val1': [1, 3, 3, 0], 
                         'val2': [5, 2, 2, 4], 
                         'val3': [5, 5, 3, 0]},
                   index=pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], name='index'))
```

| index | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 0 | 4 | 0 |

How do I only update the values in `df1` that are `True` to get the following?

| index | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | False | 5 |
| 2 | False | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | False | False | False |
| 4 | 0 | 4 | 0 |

I have tried `df1.update(df2)`, but it override the `False` values in `df1` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `where` to replace values in `df2`.

```py
# replace values
df2.where(df1, False).reset_index()
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.replace(True, pd.NA, inplace=True)
df1.update(df2, overwrite=False)
```

Output:

```
        val1   val2   val3
index                     
1          1  False      5
2      False      2      5
3      False  False  False
4          0      4      0
```